# Losing index information when using dask.dataframe.to_parquet() with partitioning

Tags: python, dask, partitioning, parquet

When I was using dask=1.2.2 with pyarrow 0.11.1 I did not observe this behavior. After updating (dask=2.10.1 and pyarrow=0.15.1), I cannot save the index when I use to_parquet method with given partition_on and write_index arguments. Here I have created a minimal example which shows the issue:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

REPORT_DATE_TEST = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01').date()
path = Path('/home/ludwik/Documents/YieldPlanet/research/trials/')

observations_nr = 3
dtas = range(0, observations_nr)
rds = [REPORT_DATE_TEST - timedelta(days=days) for days in dtas]
data_to_export = pd.DataFrame({
    'report_date': rds,
    'dta': dtas,
    'stay_date': [REPORT_DATE_TEST] * observations_nr,
    }) \
    .set_index('dta')

data_to_export_dask = dd.from_pandas(data_to_export, npartitions=1)

file_name = 'trial.parquet'
data_to_export_dask.to_parquet(path / file_name,
                               engine='pyarrow',
                               compression='snappy',
                               partition_on=['report_date'],
                               write_index=True
                              )

data_read = dd.read_parquet(path / file_name, engine='pyarrow')
print(data_read)
```

Which gives:

```
| | stay_date  |dta| report_date|
|0| 2019-01-01 | 2 | 2018-12-30 |
|0| 2019-01-01 | 1 | 2018-12-31 |
|0| 2019-01-01 | 0 | 2019-01-01 |
```

I did not see that described anywhere in the dask documentation.

Does anyone know how to save the index while partitioning the parquet data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the pyarrow's backend. I filed a bug report on their JIRA webpage:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7782

As stated by pavithraes, this issue was fixed with pyarrow 1.0.0. Thanks for letting me know! :)

Comment: After you filed this issue, looks like this has been fixed in pyarrow 1.0.0 and above. You can perhaps edit your answer to include this? :)

Answer (score 0):

I might seem like an attempt to sidestep the question, but my suggestion would be to partition along the index. This would also ensure non-overlapping indexes in the partitions.

This would be like `dd.from_pandas(data_to_export, npartitions=3)` and then skip `partition_on` and `write_index` in `to_parquet`. The index would have to be sorted.

This preserves the index and sets the divisions correctly.

Note that you are not guaranteed to get exact the number of partitions you request with `partitions`, especially not with small data sets.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but what I have shown was really a minimal example, which purpose is to isolate the issue. For certain reasons (production environment and existing data-flow) I need the partitioning on one variable, where the indexes are being conserved between reading and writing of the parquet database. The question still holds. Why did the behavior of to_parquet() change? I think it is not an intuitive behaviour, and I am not sure it was be design meant to produce such a result.